# NSFetchedResultsController and BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` that is fed by a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Everything worked fine, until I added

```
if (self.fetchedResultsController != nil) 
{
  return self.fetchedResultsController;
}
```

to the beginning of my

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
```

method.  The error I get is:

> ```
> Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
> ```

Any idea why this could be?  I declare

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController  *fetchedResultsController;
```

in the .h file and

```
@synthesize fetchedResultsController
```

in the implementation file.

Thank you~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that setting up a recursive call, with self.fetchedResultsController invoking the fetchedResultsController method?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're referencing an uninitialised pointer. Have you initialised `fetchedResultsController`? In your class's init method add:

```
fetchedResultsController = nil;
```

Does this help?